# Ubuntu Logo missing 16.04

Tags: 16.04

ihv used a script to solve ubuntu logo missing from start up and it made so called default resolution. after that my display missing. im using low resolution. no way to change it from settings. how can i solve?

Comment: Please edit and add hardware specs, graphics drivers you may have installed, intended "default resolution"...

Answer (score 1):

theres a command to change resolution hold ctrl + alt + F1 and login than type xrandr -s 1920x1080 enjoy :D

Comment: How could have you figured out 1920x1080 is the required resolution?